# MVC Views with the Same Name Issue/Bug

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

I have been using ASP.net MVC for a new website.

I have found a minor nagging issue with having views with the same name but are in different folders i.e. Views/Home/Index.aspx and Views/Account/Index.aspx
The codebehind files act as if they are partial classes when there is a definition for the same event or function (i.e. PageLoad event).  I have avoided this issue by explicitly providing a Namespace to the codebehind file (using the Folder name) and updating the reference in the markup page.

But like i said, this is annoying.  Is there something i'm not doing correctly? or is this just a bug in beta software?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not a bug in the beta software. It has nothing to do with MVC specifically or ASP.NET in general. Essentially, your problem boils down to you wanting to have two distinct classes with the same name. The only way to do this is to put them in different namespaces.